# Android - Convert audio (mp4) to array of byte

Tags: java, android, audio, arrays, mp4

i have a problem with my code, i want to convert mp4 audio files to array of bytes.
example, i have 2 audio files with different songs but the length are same, but when i print the array of bytes the result are displayed always similar, here's my code :

```
try {
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        fin = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/audiorecorder/tes.mp4");
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        byte fileContent[] = toByteArray(dis) ;

        Log.d("tes", Arrays.toString(fileContent));
    }


    catch (Exception e){}
}
public static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    copy(in,out);
    return out.toByteArray();
}





private static long copy(InputStream from, OutputStream to) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    byte[] buf = new byte[4000];
    long total = 0;
    while (true){
        int r = from.read(buf);
        if (r==-1) break;

    to.write(buf,0,r);
    total += r;
    }
    return total;
}
```